# stripe payment get payment description

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hello got this code how can i return stripe payment description to a php variable so that i can later on can use it in sql query.

```
      \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("STRIPE API");



                try {
                //Charge the Card
               $newcard = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                    "customer" => $userstrip,
                    "amount" => 400,
                    "currency" => "USD",
                    'capture' => false),
                  );

        $newcards = $newcard->description;  // Tried like this
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: Contact the vendor you got this code from for your support options. Please share them with your question.

Comment: The payment processes and creates the costumer it adds the costumer token to MySQL. But don’t know how to retrieve the payment ID and save it too

Answer (score 0):

Okay if you just use id instead of description it also gets the payment id! :)